# Библиотека C++ для быстрого рисования SVG

Tags: c++, qt, svg, поиск-библиотек

Какая библиотека на C++ существует для рисования SVG?
Использовать буду в Qt, а встроенный отрисовщик в Qt не очень шустрый.

Comment: Какая функциональность нужна: рисования в SVG (создания файлов с картинками), или для отрисовка SVG на экран?

Comment: @Chorkov Для отрисовки на экран,если дело коснется создания то для этого отдельно Qt-шный буду юзать

Comment: В Qt имеются разные классы для работы с svg: QSvgWidget,  QSvgGenerator, QGraphicsSvgItem

Comment: Можно QOpenGLWidget взять, отрисовка будет шустрой, только с форматом повозиться придётся.

Comment: а чем отличается QOpenGLWidget от QGLWidget ? это различия в версиях?
и что лучше юзать в Qt 5.12 и 5.11.3?